Logback: setting same variable multiple times
I was upgrading the versions of logback-core and logback-classic to 1.5.6 ( from 1.1.2 ), but now after upgrading I am facing the problem that my logfiles are not being created anymore.
Our logback configuration used to look like this:
  ...
  <property name="fileName" value="logA" />
  <include file="appender.xml"/>
  
  <property name="fileName" value="logB" />
  <include file="appender.xml"/>

  <property name="fileName" value="logC" />
  <include file="lappender.xml"/>
  ...

whereas appender.xml uses the fileName-property as followed:
  <appender name="${fileName}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${fileName}.log</file>
    <Append>${fileAppending}</Append>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>...</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

This used to create 3 log-files: logA, logB, logC
With the never version I only get one log-file: logC
After some debugging I saw that the properties are stored within a map and it looks like they are being resolved, before the actual xml is being processed. Since they are stored within a map, I end up with "fileName": "logC" in the properties map, before it tries to create the files. After that it tries to create 3 files with the "filename" being "logC".
I am not quite sure if this is the expected behaviour ( read and store all properties/variables before handling the content of the configuration ) since this seems quite counter-intuitive to me.
I could not find anything in the official documentation so my first question would be if this really is the behaviour to expect when setting the same property/variable multiple times?
I also tried using the variable-keyword with different scopes. I substituted the include file with the actual content of the file just to be safe. I also tried the dynamic approach by implementing a PropertyDefiner and configuring it like this:
  <define name="fileName" class="..PropertyDefiner">
    <fileName>aFileName</fileName>
  </define>

But nothing seems to work the way it used to in the older version.
Is there anything I did wrong or have missed? Or is this behaviour (to use the same variable multiple times and it being resovled when it is needed ) just not possible anymore in newer versions?

Looks like there is an open issue for my problem: https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/issues/733
